# ASP.NET MVC 4 Beta Breaks Developer Preview Projects

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

After upgrading to my ASP.NET MVC 4 Developer Preview assemblies to the latest MVC 4 beta, the following exception occurs for my MVC 4 projects:

```
Could not load type 'System.Web.WebPages.DisplayModes' from assembly
'System.Web.WebPages, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.

...

Exception Details: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type
'System.Web.WebPages.DisplayModes' from assembly 'System.Web.WebPages,
Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.
```

How do I fix this?

**Update:** I installed the new MVC 4 Beta NuGet package, which added most of the right assemblies, but now I get the missing DisplayModes error on compile:

```
The name 'DisplayModes' does not exist in the current context.
```

For the following piece of code in `Global.asax.cs`:

```
DisplayModes.Modes.Insert(0, new DefaultDisplayMode("iPhone") { ... });
```

**2nd Update:** Solved.

Comment: Do you have references to those types? Do they exist on your machine?

Comment: @gideon, I was able to update my assembly references to the latest runtime versions (4.0.30319), but `DisplayModes.Modes.Insert` sitll won't work. Has the syntax for `DisplayModes` changed?

Comment: My tutorial http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/aspnet-mvc-4-mobile-features shows the new syntax

Comment: Could you please provide more information how you solved your problem? I am facing the same. I have the MVC 4 Beta package installed. My code uses the old syntax, but IntelliSense is fine with it. When I change it to the new syntax I get an error on build.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `DisplayModes` syntax has changed to:

```
DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes.Insert(0, new DefaultDisplayMode("iPhone")
    {
    ...
    });
```

Comment: Thanks to Resharper Decompiler, I was able to discover this. It's a bit strange that MS seems to advertise the wrong method everywhere, or maybe I missed it? <strike>How or where did you find out about this?</strike>[nevermind](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/aspnet-mvc-4-mobile-features)